# What mobile app do you use to access GIS.se?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently shifted to an Android Smart phone, and I was looking at various apps to connect to Stackexchange sites in general & GIS.se in particular. I checked a few of the apps out, but they haven't been up to the mark.

Is there any particular App that you would suggest?

Comment: for GIS Apps on Android see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/list-of-gis-applications-for-android-tablets

Comment: For the last several years I have just used the stock browser on my Android phone. The mobile versions of SE sites are quite snappy, even over the air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now an answer for this two year old question.

Stack Exchange has recently released an official App for the Android platform. More details about it are available on [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/).

It is available on the Google Play store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).

A similar app for iOS is (reportedly) in the works.

Comment: I've signed up for the iOS beta so that is definitely in the pipeline - hopefully I will get my download instructions soon.

Answer (score 4):

**Stack Remote for Google Android**

**Stack Remote** is a dedicated Android app for the Stack Exchange sites like Stack Overflow, Server fault, Gaming, User Experience, Super User, etc.

This App has a current user rating of 3.7 stars.

The app uses the read-only API provided by Stack Exchange to browse view questions and answers on any of the sites from Stack Exchange. Users can also follow tags from particular sites and get notified when a new questions is posted on a followed tag. Users have the option to authenticate their accounts and check for inbox messages.

**Since this is a read-only app**, you always have the option to go to the website link, where you can post questions, answers or comments.

The app is available from Google Play (aka 'old' marketplace)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android

https://stackapps.com/questions/3178/stack-remote-free-android-app-dedicated-towards-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: TIL that the stackexchange API is read-only. That explains why all the apps are so limited.